# Oracle Dynamic SQL Open Cursor Date Parameter is Decimal

Tags: sql, oracle, date, cursor, dynamic-sql

I have the following stored procedure:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE MP9_INFORME_MUESTREOS_CABECERA
  (pPlanta IN VARCHAR2,
  pLinea IN VARCHAR2,
  pfechaini IN DATE,
  pfechafin IN DATE,
  cInformeMuestreosCabecera OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN        

OPEN cInformeMuestreosCabecera FOR

  'Select DISTINCT   
    mod_cav.id AS ID_SECCION,
    cav_mol.id AS ID_MOLDE,
    mod_lin.modelo AS MODELO,
    cav.order_fenix AS ORDEN,
    mod_cav.seccion AS SECCION, 
    cav.cavidad AS CAVIDAD,
    cav_mol.molde AS MOLDE,
    cav_mol.cavidad AS cav_mol,
    mod_lin.fecha_on AS FECHA_INICIO,
    mod_lin.fecha_off AS FECHA_FIN
  FROM
    '||pLinea||'.cnf_mod_lin mod_lin
  INNER JOIN 
    '||pLinea||'.cnf_mod_cav mod_cav 
      ON (mod_lin.fecha_on = mod_cav.fecha_on AND mod_lin.fecha_off = mod_cav.fecha_off)
  INNER JOIN 
    '||pPlanta||'.cod_cavidad cav 
      ON cav.ngotas IN (Select distinct maq_is.gotas FROM '||pLinea||'.cnf_maq_is maq_is)
 INNER JOIN 
    '||pLinea||'.cnf_cav_mol cav_mol 
      ON (mod_lin.fecha_on = cav_mol.fecha_on AND mod_lin.fecha_off = cav_mol.fecha_off 
      AND
        cav_mol.cavidad = to_char(mod_cav.seccion) ||cav.cavidad )

  WHERE
    cav_mol.status = TO_NUMBER(2)
    AND
    mod_lin.fecha_on < TO_DATE('||TO_CHAR(pfechafin)||')
    AND
    (mod_lin.fecha_off is NULL OR mod_lin.fecha_off >= TO_DATE('||TO_CHAR(pfechaini)||'))

  ORDER BY 
    mod_cav.seccion,
    cav.order_fenix';

END MP9_INFORME_MUESTREOS_CABECERA;
```

I have the error:

> ORA-01858

I change the procedure to Select directly "pfechaini" Date parameter. The result is "0.05 decimal value". I don't know where is the error.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: `The result is "0.05 decimal value".` What do you mean here? `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DATE1))` is redundant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
OPEN cInformeMuestreosCabecera FOR
  'Select ...
  WHERE ...
    mod_lin.fecha_on < :p1
    AND
    (mod_lin.fecha_off is NULL OR mod_lin.fecha_off >= :p2)
  ORDER BY ...'
USING pfechafin, pfechaini;
```